# Screen flicker on 'Lenovo ThinkPad P16 Gen 1'

Tags: display, lenovo, lightdm, thinkpad

Whenever I close the display and open it back up, the screen starts to flicker. It doesn't go away, and the only way I know to get back to normal screen is to restart the machine. I have tried lightdm, and gnome both acted similarly.

Here is a screenshot:
[image: image1]
[image: image2]

```
System config:
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

Desktop env:
lightdm

Desktop resolution:
1920x1080 at 60.01Hz and 100% scale
Fractional scaling: Disabled
```

I tried:

- [disabling Panel Self Refresh PSR](https://ljvmiranda921.github.io/notebook/2021/09/01/linux-thinkpad-screen-flicker) but that didn't help
- [Enabling](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/l0gufc/screen_tearing_on_ubuntu_20041_lts_on_my_laptop/) [modeset](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/hrsic9/im_at_a_loss_ive_had_some_issues_with_screen/) `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nvidia-drm.modeset=1 acpi_osi="` but that didn't work either

**EDIT:
I uninstalled Ubuntu and installed Fedora. The flicker is gone! I now have to deal with other issues related to packages which isn't ideal either.**

Answer (score 0):

try to set grub like this:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=! "acpi_osi=Windows 2015""

run update-grub and reboot

windows 2015 = windows 10

see on the net, may be archwiki how to get your acpi_osi SO support, mine is "Windows 20015", as i mention.